# Unity Mirror Networking InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

I was trying to create a custom player spawner but keep running into the

> "Specified cast is not valid

tried searching it online but all results were useless so hope someone here can help me.

The problem line:

```
NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, playerobject);
```

....is were the error occurs. (Full error below)

Code:

```
public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    var connection = conn;
    connlist.Add(connection);

    if (!clientLoadedScene)
    {
        if (!NetworkClient.ready) NetworkClient.Ready();
        {
            GameObject playerobject = (GameObject)Instantiate(Player, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
            playerobject.GetComponent<PlayerManager>().PlayerName = nameplayer;
            NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, playerobject);
            Debug.Log(nameplayer + " is spawned!");
        }
    }

    base.OnClientConnect(conn);
}
```

Error Full:

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
> Mirror.NetworkIdentity.SetClientOwner (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkIdentity.cs:250)
> Mirror.NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn, UnityEngine.GameObject player) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkServer.cs:617)
> NetManager.OnClientConnect (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn) (at Assets/Scripts/NetManager.cs:58)
> Mirror.NetworkManager.OnClientAuthenticated (Mirror.NetworkConnection conn) (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs:1158)
> Mirror.NetworkManager.OnClientConnectInternal () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkManager.cs:1142)
> Mirror.LocalConnectionToServer.Update () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/LocalConnections.cs:84)
> Mirror.NetworkClient.NetworkLateUpdate () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkClient.cs:1249)
> Mirror.NetworkLoop.NetworkLateUpdate () (at Assets/Mirror/Runtime/NetworkLoop.cs:189)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure which line you're getting the error on but from what I can remember the `Instantiate()` method returns a `GameObject` so you wouldn't need to cast it, additionally you shouldn't be storing your connection `var` in a list if you intend to keep it, your revised code should be something like:

```
public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
{
    connlist.Add(conn);

    if (!clientLoadedScene)
    {
        if (!NetworkClient.ready) NetworkClient.Ready();
        {
            var playerobject = Instantiate(Player, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
            playerobject.GetComponent<PlayerManager>().PlayerName = nameplayer;
            NetworkServer.AddPlayerForConnection(conn, playerobject);
            Debug.Log(nameplayer + " is spawned!");
        }
    }

    base.OnClientConnect(conn);
}
```

Comment: Yea that was just after i got the bug I was trying a lot I didn't remove it yet but The AddPlayerForConnection is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution i moved my Spawn code to a function that is OnServerAddPlayer instead of OnClientConnect it fixes all the problems and works amazing!